# How do I add the JavaScript src file inside a block?

Tags: javascript, blocks

I have called the JavaScript source code, `<script scr=""></script>`, inside a block. And this code is working fine.

But I am not sure whether it's good practice or not.

If it's not a good practice, give me some suggestions for adding above code inside the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add javascript [as a library](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module), then attach it to your block in the build array or a preprocess function like this:

```
$block['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule.search_filters';
$block['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mymodule'] = [
  'cats' => 'tabby',
  'dogs' => 'dalmation',
];
```